# Only allow specific roles to use a command

Tags: discord.py

I've been making a command to change a user's role, but currently, everyone can use it. I've tried doing a few things.
Here is my code:

```py
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"I gave {user.name} the role {role.name}")
```

Here is the only thing that I've been able to think of:

```
allowed = ["Role 1"]
if message.author.role in allowed:
   async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
      await user.add_roles(role)
      await ctx.send(f"I gave {user.name} the role {role.name}")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just add [`@commands.has_any_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_any#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role):

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_roles("Role 1", "Role 2")
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"I gave {user.name} the role {role.name}")
```

If the user isn't allowed to use the command, it will raise a [`commands.MissingAnyRole`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_any#discord.ext.commands.MissingAnyRole) error.